"Loops Of Zen"-ish solitaire

That should explain everything.
It doesn't? OK. A "tile" is a 3*3 square. Color subsquares white and black.
Rules: No checkerboard pattern wbwb around a point (i.e. no crossing lines).
Since only the implied lines are relevant, you may always swap white and
black to get the same tile. Rotated tiles are also equivalent, mirrored not.
In this way you get exactly 44 tiles, plus one "degenerate" (the loop in
the middle). Place it in the middle of a 7*7 square of tiles and leave
the corners free (I placed some placeholders there in the image).
Place all tiles so that colors match at the borders (or rather, lines
match on the borders, since you may swap colors). (EDIT: The outermost border is thought to be white and must also match, but this is implicite from the "one big loop".) Accidently, this is
possible - see image. (If lines match, coloring will follow -
Jordan curve theorem.)
If you try this for yourself, you will quickly run into line loops.
The image shows a more difficult version of the puzzle - it is one
single big loop. (Not counting the center.)
Can you beat my example in "thinness" (number of black squares)?
(You may have more than one loop, I doubt my example can be
beaten if you do the harder version with one loop.)
Or "fatness"? (If the border is white, the center square may
as well be white too - think Jordan curve theorem again.)
EDIT2: I wrote a little Python program. There are exactly 25 additional tiles (unique under the same conditions) with crossings. Maybe they can also form a square - I didn't try yet.
